# ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, electron

I'm working on a project based on the [Angular Electron Repo](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/tree/angular4), using the Angular 4 versions. When I try to run `npm run electron:mac`, which in turn runs `webpack --display-error-details`, the webpack build runs until it hits this error message:

```
[XS25] ./src/polyfills.ts 2.45 kB {0} [built]
   [0] multi ./src/main.ts 28 bytes {2} [built]
[dvQ4] ./src/environments/index.ts 252 bytes {2} [built]
[kke6] ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 3.16 kB {2} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[x35b] ./src/main.ts 376 bytes {2} [built]
   [1] multi ./src/polyfills.ts 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] multi ./src/styles.scss 28 bytes {1} [built]
    + 147 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at resolveAlias (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:24003:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42692:26)
    at checkImportBinding (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42722:13)
    at checkImportDeclaration (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42740:29)
    at checkSourceElement (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43052:28)
    at Object.forEach (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1500:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43125:20)
    at checkSourceFile (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43105:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43169:17)
    at getDiagnostics (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43155:24)
    at Object.getEmitResolver (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:23078:13)
    at /Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70539:69
    at runWithCancellationToken (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70295:24)
    at getDeclarationDiagnosticsForFileNoCache (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70538:20)
    at getAndCacheDiagnostics (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70551:26)
    at getDeclarationDiagnosticsWorker (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70535:20)
    at getDeclarationDiagnosticsForFile (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70564:56)
    at getDiagnosticsHelper (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70254:24)
    at Object.getDeclarationDiagnostics (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70276:24)
    at TypeScriptFileRefactor.getDiagnostics (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/refactor.js:52:60)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then (/Users/Evan/Documents/Programming/electron/groupme-client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:505:46)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I'm not sure what the error message is referring to, no part of my application uses the property `flags`, including in `app.module.ts` or `main.ts`.

I have seen many answers and threads which contain solutions for installing various versions of packages. Things such as upgrading `@angular/cli` to 1.7.3 and upgrading Typescript to 2.6.2 have only caused other issues. I believe that the issue is not with my installed modules, as the Angular Electron repo provides a working application with an identical set of modules in `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel webpack:watch electron:serve",
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start:web": "webpack-dev-server --content-base . --port 4200 --inline",
    "build:electron:main": "tsc main.ts --outDir dist && copyfiles package.json dist && cd dist && npm install --prod && cd ..",
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details && npm run build:electron:main",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run build",
    "electron:serve": "npm run build:electron:main && electron ./dist --serve",
    "electron:test": "electron ./dist",
    "electron:dev": "npm run build && electron ./dist",
    "electron:prod": "npm run build:prod && electron ./dist",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && node package.js --asar --platform=darwin --arch=x64",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet && npm run build",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.6",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.4",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "copyfiles": "1.2.0",
    "cross-env": "5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "3.10.0",
    "electron": "1.7.8",
    "electron-packager": "9.1.0",
    "electron-reload": "1.2.1",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "postcss-url": "7.1.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "0.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "stylus-loader": "3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
    "webpack": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2"
  },
```

I'm very much out of answers here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after i used

```
ng update
```

and I resolved the issue by reverting my package.json to the previous version of angular,

I downgraded from 6.1.3 to 6.0.7

Comment: All three of those steps completed successfully, but ultimately executing my original command still resulted in the aforementioned error.

Comment: I changed my answer for you, please try downgrading angular version.

Comment: I am using Angular 4.4.6, so i'm not sure what version you are suggesting I downgrade to?